# Path-dependent Types and Type Projection

Tags: scala

As I understand the `def bar(x: X#Inner)` signature, it simply requires **any** instance of `Inner` to compile successfully. Whereas, `foo(x: this.Inner)` will only compile with the same `Outer.Inner` class instance.

While reading [Scala in Depth](http://www.manning.com/suereth/), I put this code into REPL, but I'm getting a compile-time error.

```
scala> class Outer {
     |    trait Inner
     |     def y = new Inner {}
     |    def foo(x: this.Inner) = null
     |    def bar(x: X#Inner) = null
     | }
<console>:11: error: not found: type X
          def bar(x: X#Inner) = null
                     ^
```

Also, what is the compile-time error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `X` in `X#Inner` refers to the outer type. You do not have a type `X` anywhere, that's what the compiler error says exactly.

In your example you will want to refer to type `Outer` instead:

```
class Outer {
  trait Inner
  def foo(x: this.Inner) = ???
  def bar(x: Outer#Inner) = ???
}
```

Comment: thanks, @0__. Out of curiosity, why did you write `def foo(x: this .Inner)` with the whitespace between `this` and `.Inner`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith obsession with vertically aligning similar lines :)

Answer (score 0):

`X#Inner` should be `Outer#Inner`，I think the author of `Scala in depth` just typed falsely in the book.